# Google Colaboratory: 'No backend with GPU available'. Why is this?

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I'm using Google Colabs GPU to train multiple Convolutional Neural Networks. It's been going relatively fine but since yesterday I get a message that says there is 'no backend with GPU available.

Personally, I thought that you could use their GPU's endlessly, just keeping in mind that one can only train for 12-hour stretches at maximum. However, now I can't get a backend with GPU. I've tried restarting runtime multiple times and logging in/out, but can't get a GPU anymore. I asked a friend of mine to check if he could get a backend with GPU, and it worked just fine for him.

This makes me think that it's not an issue on Google's side, but at my side. What could be possible causes for this and how could I get a GPU on Colab again? Could it be that they blocked me out because I'm using them too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: As of February, 2020, [the FAQ](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html#resource-limits) has been updated with much more information on usage limits and a pointer to [Colab Pro](https://colab.research.google.com/signup) for users in need of higher limits.

My original answer follows.

Seems to be answered by the [FAQ](http://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html).

Quoting:

> **How may I use GPUs and why are they sometimes unavailable?**
>
> Colaboratory is intended for interactive use. Long-running background
>   computations, particularly on GPUs, may be stopped. Please do not use
>   Colaboratory for cryptocurrency mining. Doing so is unsupported and
>   may result in service unavailability. We encourage users who wish to
>   run continuous or long-running computations through Colaboratory’s UI
>   to use a [local runtime](http://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html).

It seems that limits on GPU access are periodically reset, so you're likely to be able to access a GPU again later after waiting for some time for cooldown.

Comment: I've got this message on Colab Pro :(

Comment: Anyone knows how much time does one has to wait for cooldown ?

Answer (score 1):

The cooldown time for reusing the GPU seems to be approximately 12 hours, because I was blocked at around 3 pm yesterday and just granted access to it at 9:50 am today. It might vary on the current GPU usage of google colab and some other factors.

EDIT: The cooldown time increases when you get banned multiple times(can't use it for nearly one week). COLAB PRO guarantees 24h GPU runtimes w/o bans.

Comment: are you saying that colab pro allows me to run on gpu for 24h even mining without ban?

Comment: After using for 24 h, you get like a 5h ban. This is repeated again and again. The ban doesn't seem to be permanent and the ban time doesn't seem to increase. But please don't mine using COLAB :(

Comment: @LuisFelipe I think you still can be banned for mining crypro. The ban I mentioned was more of a cooldown for overtime usage(that happen~3h into training). I remember COLAB has another mechanism to detect and ban crypto mining. In this case PRO wont evade bans.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I was training a ResNet for a few hours and the next day I was unable to use any colab resource